# Is there any significant meaning for `.d.ts` filenames except for readability?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, vuejs3, typescript-declarations

In my project, there's a `shims-vue.d.ts` file under `src` folder:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Even if I rename `shims-vue.d.ts` to `foo.d.ts`, the declarations still take effect, so I'm wondering is there any significant meaning for `.d.ts` filenames except for readability?

Since whatever I renamed it to, its declarations still work without manually importing the renamed `.d.ts` file.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking here - Typescript is not Java, there is no rule saying that a filename has to match something in the source code. It doesn't matter whether it's a `.ts`, `.d.ts`, `.tsx` file or whatever else.

Comment: The question is asking whether declaration file naming has any runtime significance - afaik I can put type declarations in `foo.d.ts`, `index.d.ts`, and `whatever-else.d.ts` and still have them picked up by `tsc`. @zeeshan-siddiqui that explains _what_ a declaration file is, but doesn't mention anything about file naming.

Comment: Notably, picked up by `tsc` _without specifying their name anywhere_ (unlike `.ts`/`.tsx`/`.js`/`.jsx`, where you still have to specify the filename, to address @kaya3). For comparison, `index.js` has runtime significance (importing `foo` and `foo/index.js` are equivalent); are there any similar properties to declaration files?

Comment: @superhawk610 I specify `"rootDir": "src"` in my `tsconfig.json` and then I don't have to specify the names of `.ts` files anywhere; `tsc` will just compile all of them from that directory.

Comment: @kaya3 sure, but to actually use any `.ts` file (apart from `index.ts`), you have to explicitly import it _by name_. You don't have to specify `.d.ts` files by name anywhere, but they're still made ambiently available - so, do `.d.ts` file names matter? Or are they just semantic?

Comment: @superhawk610 If your `.ts` files have export declarations then you have to import them by name, if not then you don't. I don't see how this is related to the question, though; you could choose a meaningful filename and import by that name, or you could choose a meaningless filename and import by that name, and the answer to "does the filename have any meaning?" would be different. If the question is about *runtime* significance then the answer is trivial - type declarations just don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @superhawk610 you summarized much better than I did, feel free to edit the question if you feel it's vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaration file represents type definitions for another, JavaScript file (module). Declared module name has to match name of physical JavaScript file that will be imported.

For example, for following to work correctly, both for typings, but also for runtime import:

```typescript
import { $ } from "jquery";
```

Your declared module name has to be named "jquery", because your JavaScript file is `jquery.js`:

```typescript
declare module "jquery" {
    /...
}
```

It's not important how you named the declaration file `jquery.d.ts` or `my-declaration.d.ts`, etc, as long as declared module name is correct and corresponds to physical JavaScript file.

Module declarations also support wild-cards in the name, so in your case `*.vue` represents default "shape" of any `*.vue` file (`main.vue`, `page1.vue`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `d.ts` files naming is relevant for module resolution. When resolving `import Foo from 'module'`, `tsc` will lookup `module.ts` first and then `module.d.ts`. Most likely for your case `tsc` is still finding the declarations using other strategies, like a `types` or `baseUrl` config.

If you want to better understand how this works, this command can be helpful

```sh
tsc --traceResolution | grep -B 20 "shims-vue.d.ts"
```

That is completely fine, but, for instance, this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7624) is a good example of how `.d.ts` file naming does matter.

See the [module resolution docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) for a more detailed explanation.